# How to capture all substrings in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string like this:**temp_input='[a1b] hjh [d;] , [45]'**. I want to capture all substrings between the pair of [] (without "[" and "]"). I have googled alot and get this:

```
temp_input='[a1b] hjh [d;] , [45]'
if [[ $temp_input =~ \[[^\]]+\] ]]
then
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}                   // [a1b]
fi
```

If i can get all matches with only =~ operator?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `If i can get all matches with only =~ operator?` -- No.

Comment: @devnull: Yes, you can. It depends on the regex, though.

Comment: @choroba Yes, by looping one can.  I am (and was) aware of that.  I've added another approach in addition to the ones described by you.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You can build the regular expression dynamically (you just remember the result of the longest matching regex):

```
#! /bin/bash
temp_input='[a1b] hjh [d;] , [45]'

regex='\[(.*)\]'
for (( i=0 ; i<${#temp_input}/2 ; i++ )) ; do
    regex+='.*\[(.*)\]'
    if [[ $temp_input =~ $regex ]] ; then
        matches=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]}")
    fi
done

for (( m=1; m<${#matches[@]} ; m++ )) ; do
    echo "${matches[m]}"
done
```

Here is how you can do it *without* the `=~` operator, iterating over the input character by character:

```
#! /bin/bash
temp_input='[a1b] hjh [d;] , [45]'

matches=()
string=''
in=0

for ((i=0 ; i<${#temp_input} ; i++)) ; do
    char=${temp_input:i:1}
    if ((in)) ; then
        if [[ $char == ] ]] ; then
            in=0
            matches+=("$string")
            string=''
        else
            string+=$char
        fi
    fi
    if [[ $char == [ ]] ; then
        in=1
    fi
done

for m in "${matches[@]}" ; do
    echo "$m"
done
```

Or shorter, using a different type of parameter expansion + pattern matching:

```
#! /bin/bash
temp_input='[a1b] hjh [d;] , [45]'

matches=()
while [[ $temp_input == *\[*\]* ]] ; do
    temp_input=${temp_input#*[}
    t=${temp_input%%]*}
    matches+=("$t")
done

for m in "${matches[@]}" ; do
    echo "$m"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `read` to *split* the input string by delimiters and use shell parameter expansion to strip the undesired part:

```
temp_input='[a1b] hjh [d;] , [45]'

while read -d ']' foo; do
  echo "${foo##*[}"
done <<< "${temp_input}"
```

This would produce:

```
a1b
d;
45
```

Better still, replace

```
  echo "${foo##*[}"
```

with

```
  [[ $foo == *[* ]] && echo "${foo##*[}"
```

and the script would also handle inputs like `foo]`.

<sub>You could also use `grep`.  Say `grep -oP '(?<=\[)[^[]*(?=\])' input` (assuming your version of `grep` supports PCRE)</sub>